# ¿Cómo hago para que, desde un botón en el MainActivity, abra el fragment que he creado para reproducir un video?

Tags: android, android-fragment, botón

Tengo en el MainActivity, aparte de un botón que reproduce directamente un audio, otro botón debajo que quiero que abra un fragment que ya he creado previamente para que se reproduzca un video. El problema es que por mucho que intente nunca lo consigo; siempre cuando ejecuto o la app directamente se cierra, abre otra app que tenga o cuando le pulso al botón del video durante un milisegundo sí se pone la pantalla en negro como sí a punto de reproducirse el video pero inmediatamente se cierra la app.

¿Cómo se supone que lo tengo que hacer?

Aquí tenéis los códigos que tengo hecho hasta ahora:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MediaPlayer mp;
Button btnAudio;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnAudio = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_audio);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.doot);
    btnAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_audio"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Audio" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_video"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Video" /></LinearLayout>
```

RVideoFragment.java:

```
public class RVideoFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button btnPlay;
private VideoView video;
private boolean reproduciendo;
private OnRVideoFragmentListener mListener;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    View vistaLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_rvideo_fragment, container, false);
    video = vistaLayout.findViewById(R.id.video);
    btnPlay = vistaLayout.findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
    String path = "android:resource://"+getActivity().getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.skeleton;
    video.setVideoPath(path);
    video.setMediaController(new MediaController(getActivity()));
    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
    reproduciendo = false;
    return vistaLayout;
}

public static RVideoFragment newInstance() {
    RVideoFragment mFragment = new RVideoFragment();
    return mFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);}

public interface OnRVideoFragmentListener {
    void onClickVideo();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnRVideoFragmentListener) {
        mListener = (OnRVideoFragmentListener) context;
    }
    else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()+" debe implementar OnListFragmentListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (!reproduciendo) {
        video.start();
        reproduciendo = true;
        btnPlay.setText("Pausa");
    }
    else {
        video.pause();
        reproduciendo = false;
        btnPlay.setText("Play");
    }
}}
```

activity_rvideo_fragment.xml (aunque ponga activity, se supone que es un fragment):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".RVideoFragment"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_play"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Play" />

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ok al cerrase que se muestra como error en el LogCat? , si deseas desarrollar en Android el uso del LogCat es indispensable.

Comment: Ahora ya no puedo. Mañana por el mediodía/tarde veo eso del LogCat que dices y te digo.

Answer (score 0):

LO primero que tienes que hacer es incluir tu clase del fragment a tu MainActivity

```
    RVideoFragment rvideofragment;
```

Luego en el Oncreate instanciarlo:  `rvideofragment = new RVideoFragment();`

en tu método onClick implementa:

```
  FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().commit;

 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.TucontenedordeFragmet,rvideofragment).commit();
```

Esa es la forma de navegar entre Fragments

Comment: La pregunta es porque se cierra, esto de acuerdo a el código que muestra el OP, saludos.

Comment: He hecho eso y se me sigue cerrando inmediatamente la app.Y, por lo del LogCat, lo que me sale es en el desplegable en rojo "No debuggable processes" y luego en la caja de mensajes unos cuantos errores: "couldn't load memtrack module", "failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.wellbeing.api", "failed to open QEMU pipe", "WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe" y "Error writing app idle file for user 0.

Comment: He probado ya de todas las maneras habidas y por haber y no hay @#$ manera de que el video vaya, siempre se cierra la app o no hace nada de nada. Nunca me sale error en java, siempre los errores son de Memtrack, QEMU y com.google

Answer (score 0):

Alejandro, ya he hecho el código como me has dicho pero me sigue pasando lo mismo de que se me cierra inmediatamente la app y me salen unos cuantos errores en el LogCat que ya le detallo a Jorgesys en un comentario aquí.

Así es como tengo mi MainActivity.java ahora:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MediaPlayer mp;
Button btnAudio;
Button btnVideo;
RVideoFragment rVideoFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnAudio = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_audio);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.doot);
    btnAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });

    rVideoFragment = new RVideoFragment();
    btnVideo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_video);
    btnVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, rVideoFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: escribiendo tal cual como me dices la primera linea (FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().commit; me da error